# Action method never invoked

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

I'm working on a java web application with play framework 1.2.4. In my view, I try to invoke a method in the controller but it doesn't work.
Here is the view code :

```
%{ url='/'+lang+'/artists/item?.name?.asString()+'-'+item?.id?.asString(); }% 
<a href="${url}"></a>
```

So the url is something like `localhost:9000/en/artists/artistName-artistId`, 
for the action code :

```
public static void artistView(String lang, String artistName, String artistId, String mode)  {
    //my code here
            }
```

the routes conf :

```
GET     /{<(fr)|(en)|(ar)>lang}/artists/{artistName}-{<[0-9]{32}>artistId}                                                      MyControllerName.artistView(mode:'overview')
```

With this, my action is never invoked. What did I do wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: artistId has exactly 32 digits?

Comment: No, not really. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: `{<[0-9]{32}>artistId}` routes pass if regexp match, this one defines artistsId as exactly 32 digits long word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I see your URL is wrong, it should be:

```
%{ url='/'+lang+'/artists/'+item?.name?.asString()+'-'+item?.id?.asString(); }%
```

Anyway, I think you can fix it.

Second, I think you want your artistId is the number from 1 character to 32 characters, not exactly 32 characters.

So, route.conf should be:

```
GET     /{<(fr)|(en)|(ar)>lang}/artists/{artistName}-{<[0-9]{,32}>artistId}                                                      MyControllerName.artistView(mode:'overview')
```

Please read more about Regular Expression if you want to know why?

Note: `(mode:'overview')` will be no effect. If you want to set default, please do it in your controller like:

```
if (mode == null) mode = "overview";
```

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the issue was indeed in the regex